# How to type hint a list with a particular structure

Tags: python, list, type-hinting, typing

I have a data structure in my code that (for the sake of an [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.)) is a list where the first element is a string, and the second element is an integer. For example:

`foo: MyStructure = ["hello", 42]`.

Now, since there is an ordering to this structure, usually I would use a tuple and instead do:

`foo: Tuple[str, int] = ("hello", 42)`.

But I explicitly want to be able to easily modify elements within the structure. In particular, I want to be able to set `foo[0] = "goodbye"`, which cannot be done if `foo` is a tuple.

**What is the best way to go about typing this structure?**

(I don't think that this question is opinion-based, since I think there is likely clear rationale for how to handle this that would be preferred by most developers.)

Right now, the main solution I can think of is to not actually type the structure correctly, and instead to define my own structure whose true type is listed in a comment:

```
# MyStructure = [str, int]
MyStructure = List[Union[str, int]]

foo: MyStructure = ["hello", 42]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: In the static typing world, lists are homogenous. If you want a mutable tuple, define a custom class (which, like a tuple, can be thought of as a product type).

Comment: Would this have to be a full-fledged class, or would I just be defining a special type? (If the latter, how would I go about doing this?)

Comment: Almost! Similar question, except for in my question I explicitly say that the top answer to that question won’t work in my case and explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a list or a tuple; you want a custom class representing the type-level product of `str` and `int`. A dataclass is particularly useful here.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MyStructure:
    first: str
    second: int


foo: MyStructure = MyStructure("hello", 42)

assert foo.first == "hello"
assert foo.second = 42
```

If you really want to access the components using integer indices, you can add a `__getitem__` method to the class:

```
@dataclass
class MyStructure:
    first: str
    second: int

    def __getitem__(self, key) -> Union[str,int]:
        if key == 0:
            return self.first
        elif key == 1:
            return self.second
        else:
            raise IndexError(key)
```

In addition, an instance of `MyStructure` uses less memory than the corresponding list:

```
>>> foo = MyStructure("hello", 42)
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(foo)
48
>>> sys.getsizeof(["hello", 42])
72
```

Comment: I'm particularly using lists because I was running into runtime and memory issues when using classes. While this is helpful, using a full-fledged class will add extra overhead that I do not want to incur.

Comment: An instance of `MyStructure` will use less memory than the list `["hello", 42]`.

Comment: You are correct; thank you for pointing that out! However, it takes about 6 times as long to initialize, so there is some tradeoff involved.

Comment: Does that matter? Is the time it takes to initialize your object going to be a bottleneck in your program?

Comment: @ProQ If you really care about construction speed you could try out [slotted `attrs` classes](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#slots). Creating an instance of the dataclass in this example takes ~322ns, while for the slotted class it takes ~268ns. If you choose to write your own slots class you can also shave off a few ns and achieve ~240ns. However, unless this really is a bottleneck to you (e.g. if you need to create billions of such objects), you usually don't need to go to extreme lengths to optimize it.